# Is it possible to test a Windows application for XP compatibility without running XP?

Tags: windows-xp, compatibility, abi

Even though the EOS date for Windows XP is quickly approaching many of our users are still using it and will likely continue to do so for some time. I'd like keep supporting them as long as possible while at the same time minimize the use XP in our build environment. Is it possible to test an application for XP compatibility on a newer version of Windows?

I'm looking for a static or dynamic ABI checker similar to Solaris' [`appcert` or `apptrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-5042/6mb7bck7e/index.html).